# How to resize QLabels to fit contents in QScrollArea

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

This issue is specific to PyQt5, but C++ Qt5 answers are fine too.

Within a QScrollArea with fixed width and variable height, I have a `QVBoxLayout` that contains `QLabel`s. These `QLabels` have `setWordWrap(True)` and contain text which may be longer than the fixed width of the `QScrollArea`. When the text inside a `QLabel` wraps to ~4 lines, everything works fine, but when the `QLabel` requires more than that, it fails to continue increasing the height of the `QLabel`, and cuts off some of the text on the top and bottom.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293507/) tried to fix essentially the same issue, which involves setting the `QLabel`'s vertical `sizePolicy()` to `MinimumExpanding`, and this *technically* worked, but it will force the `QLabels` to try and fill the entire `QScrollArea` viewport if the viewport hasn't been filled with `QLabel`s yet.

Here's how it currently looks without the `sizePolicy` set to `MinimumExpanding` (notice the 1st `QLabel`):

[image: sizePolicy not set]

Here's how it looks when `MinimumExpanding` is set as the vertical size policy of the `QLabel`s (Looks great...):

[image: sizePolicy set]

But it results in this behavior when there is only a few `QLabel`s in the scroll area, which is unacceptable behavior, as this is going to be a "comments" service, where people can post their questions in plain text:

[image: unacceptable behavior]

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue, or experience anything similar to it?

For reference, here is some of my code:

```
class NewsList(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewsList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMaximumWidth(200)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        layout.setSpacing(5)
        layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.news_widget = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.news_widget.setStyleSheet("""
            QFrame {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        """)
        self.news_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWidget(self.news_widget)
        self.fetch_news()

    def fetch_news(self):
        self.append_message('DSADAISH dshadbsasdsadh sd ashd sah dsha dhsa dsa d')
        self.append_message('DSADAISH dshadbsasdsadh sd ashd sah dsha dhsa dsa d')
        self.append_message('DSADAISH dshadbsasdsadh sd ashd sah dsha dhsa dsa d DSADAISH dshadbsasdsadh sd ashd sah dsha dhsa dsa d')
        self.append_message('DSADAISH ')
        self.append_message('DSADAISH ')
        self.append_message('DSADAISH dshadbsasdsadh sd ashd sah dsha dhsa dsa d')
        self.append_message('DSADAISH dshadbsasdsadh sd ashd sah dsha dhsa dsa d')

    def append_message(self, text):
        new_item = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        new_item.setWordWrap(True)
        new_item.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                padding: 4px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        """)
```

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with the second image ?, I do not understand when you say: *But it is in this behavior when there is only a few QLabels in the scroll area, which is unacceptable behavior, as this is going to be a "comments" service, where can people post their questions in plain text:*

Comment: The two `QLabels` that I showed in the example image should take up a minimum amount of height such that it fits only the text inside. However, with `MinimumExpanding` set on the label, this expands the `QLabel`'s height to the height of the viewport. The container holding the Labels is a `ScrollArea`.

Comment: Apologies, got confused by "second image", thought you meant "third image." In the second image, it looks great as is, but having `QLabels` NOT take up the ENTIRE viewport results in the third image, which is explained in the above comment.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain me about the second image, what is the problem ?, I see that the labels occupy a minimum height that only shows the necessary text. Or do you mean that the scrollbar does not appear ?, In addition I just tried your code and a QScrollArea appears empty.

Comment: You could show an image of how you want it to be a second image.

Comment: The second image is the result of the `MinimumExpanding` flag being set on the `QLabels` and it presents correct behavior when the number of widgets "fills" the `QScrollArea`, however, when QLabels are a small number and only fill the current viewport partially, they expand to fill the given viewport, seen in image 3. This is not what I want, I want the `QLabel`s to shrink and take up the minimum height required to fit the text similar to image 2. Also, I edited the code so it should work now.

Comment: Now I understand, you could correct your code because when I execute it, there is only an empty QScrollArea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved quite simply by using the [`addStretch`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) method of the layout that contains the news items:

```
class NewsList(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...    
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        layout.setSpacing(5)
        layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        # add a stretchable space to the bottom of the layout
        layout.addStretch(1)

    def append_message(self, text):
        ...
        # set the size policy of the label
        new_item.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        # insert the label before the spacer        
        layout = self.news_widget.layout()
        layout.insertWidget(layout.count() - 1, new_item)
```

The spacer pushes the labels upwards, which stops them streching to take up the available space. Using the *stretch-factor* argument of `addStretch` ensures that the spacer always takes precedence over the other items in the layout.